# Error while running React Native project on Android: A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-gesture-handler'

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, gradle, react-native-gesture-handler

I am trying to run a React Native project on Android. I have imported the project from GitHub(https://github.com/Kaiwenkevinz/RandomChat.git) to my local machine, and I have proceeded to run the commands `npm install` and `npx react-native run-android` as instructed. However, I encountered an error during the `npx react-native run-android` process.

The specific error message I received is:
[image]

I have tried researching this issue on various forums and documentation, but I haven't been able to find a solution that works for me. I believe this error might be related to the configuration or dependencies of the project.

Here's some additional information about my setup:

Operating System: Windows

React Native version: `9.6.7` (by `npm react-native -v`)

Node.js version: `v18.17.1` (by `node -v`)

Android studio version: `Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1 Patch 1`

Project structrue: Android API 33

build.gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33

        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
    }
}
```

I think it's due to issues with the Gradle or Kotlin versions, which is causing the inability to run, but I haven't found a good solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add this klotin version and

[image]

and in your package.json verify if you've this version of
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.8.0",

I hope this may help.

Comment: Now it works, but then in login page when I type username and password it reports another error: `[Error: Native crypto module could not be used to get secure random number]` Now I am trying to solve this issue.

Comment: Hi, if my answer solved your first question please, mark it as a solution! For your second question, I advise use to create another question about it, or share your project on code sandbox or Git Hub.

Comment: Ok, I've marked it!